# Брожу ли я вдоль улиц шумных

Tags: грамматика, сложное-предложение

***Брожу ли я вдоль улиц шумных,***

***Вхожу ль во многолюдный храм,***

***Сижу ль меж юношей безумных,***

***Я предаюсь моим мечтам.***

Автор: А. С. Пушкин

Как сделать **грамматический разбор** этого  предложения (вид, отношения между его частями, средства связи)?

Мне такой разбор **не кажется очевидным**, поэтому хотелось бы услышать мнение участников форума.

Спасибо.